# Should I refer to "Section 2.3" or "Subsection 2.3"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, writing, syntactic-analysis

When writing a document that is divided into numbered sections and subsections, sometimes I would like to refer a certain subsection that has been numbered 2.3, for example.  Here the 2 represents the section number and 3 is the subsection number within section 2.

**Question**: Should I refer to "Section 2.3" or "Subsection 2.3"?

To me, the latter seems tautological (or at least not completely necessary) since the "sub-" component of "subsection" is implied by the number 2.3 itself.

Comment: This may be defined by your company/organization's style manual. For example, perhaps it tells you to put in simply "2.3".

Answer (score 15):

I have to agree with you.

Collins Dictionary defines "subsection":

> a section of a section; subdivision

It is certainly grammatically correct to use either word, and I think it is semantically correct both ways as well. However, as you say, writing "Subsection 2.3" it introducing redundancy, as it is (as you say) blatantly obvious that section 2.3 is a subsection of section 2.

I would say, however, that "Section 2.3" does not imply a subsection, it seems rather explicit that it is a subsection, to me.

A quick search on Google for "Section 2.3" and "Subsection 2.3": Section has 1.2 million hits. Subsection has 46,000 hits. So it definitely makes much more sense to drop the "sub-".

If we have the document:

> 1. Birds
>      1.1. Parrots
>
>    This is a  bunch of information about parrots.
>
>    1.2. Hawks
>
>    This is a bunch of information about hawks.

Both "Parrots" and "Hawks" are sections in their own right. They are simply sections within sections.

This is similar to the folder metaphor in computing. A folder contains many subfolders, but each subfolder is still a complete, and real, folder in its own right.

Princeton University's WordNet defines [subsection](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=subsection):

> (n) subsection, subdivision (a section of a section; a part of a part; i.e., a part of something already divided)

Furthermore, Merriam-Webster defines [section](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/section):

> a distinct part or portion of something written (as a chapter, law, or newspaper)

So if one takes a section, then takes another logical portion of that, that is another section–also a subsection–that happens to be inside the original section.

E.g. a chapter is a *section* of a book. A paragraph is a *section* of a chapter. A sentence is a *section* of a paragraph. We can logically divide anything into however we like.

Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary defines [subsection](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/subsection):

> one of the smaller parts into which the main parts of a document or organization are divided
>   *Further details can be found in section 7 subsection 4 of the report.*

From the example, we can see that they have referred to section 7.4 as section 7, subsection 4.

My understanding of all this, is that we can call top-level sections, just "section". But we can call non-top-level sections either "section" OR "subsection".

Comment: What on earth does that Google search prove? If the things are broken into chapters, then that would mean that it actually was section 2.3 and not referring to a subsection at all.

Comment: The Google search proves common usage. Common usage is what makes English English.

Comment: @Vincent: you've missed my point - if the document is divided into chapter 1, 2, 3 and section 1.1, section 2.3 then "section 2.3" would be the correct name. If the document is divided into section 1, 2, 3 then one would expect subsection 1.1, subsection 2.3, etc.

Comment: So you would refer to C:\Users\Vincent\Documents as a sub-sub-sub-folder? Or would you simply call it a folder?

Comment: @Vincent: sorry you have completely lost me, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Vincent: I agree with your presentation of what a section is (+1) even though I believe having made a legitimate case for using subsection (i.e. emphasizing the "subordinate" aspect of its content)

Comment: You both (@Shinto and @Vincent) could have up voted each other to benefit both instead of down voting each other and loosing reputation. :D

Answer (score 4):

In law, you clarify what you are talking about when referring to a subsection by saying "Subsection 23 (1)" or in spoken English you would say "subsection twenty-three, one". You can also say "Section twenty-three, Subsection one".

The purpose of saying "subsection" twenty-three (1) is to set in the mind of the listener or reader, that you are going to refer to a subsection, not the section the subsection you are referring to is subordinate to.

**Statute Example:**

```
23 All dog leashes shall be solid blue in color unless;

 (1) The dog is a seeing-eye-dog, then the leash used on this type of dog shall be solid yellow in color.
```

Using the statute example above, a person who is reading this law could say that according to subsection twenty-three, one, a person with a seeing-eye-dog has to use a solid yellow leash.

They could also say that according to section twenty-three, subsection one, a person with a seeing-eye-dog has to use a solid yellow leash.

Answer (score 3):

When referring to a section and a subsection (or a paragraph and sub-paragraph, etc) the abbreviation that corresponds to the highest 'level' of the section (or paragraph, etc) should be used -- for example, using the *Section Designation Guidelines* from DBSK_FAN and imagining that it was taken from 'Chapter 9 - Witty Examples', you would say 'chapter 9, section 4' - ***not*** 'sub-chapter 9, 4'; you would say 'section 4' ***not*** 'sub-chapter 4'; you would say 'section 4(a)' - ***not*** 'subsection 4(a)'; and you would say 'section 4(a)(i)' ***not*** 'subsection 4(a)(i)' ***nor*** 'sub-subsection 4(a)(i)' ***nor*** 'double-sub-section 4(a)(i)'.

The only times you say 'subsection' at all would be, eg, 'section 4, subsection (a)' (and that's only when actually saying it out loud  - like in court or whatever - as opposed to typing or writing it); or when you are writing about section 4 in an essay and then, having made it very clear you are talking solely about chapter 9, section 4, you go on to discuss the correlation or contradiction or whatever between subsections (a) and (b).

Those are the rules you're supposed to abide by at Australian law faculties, anyway. Google the AGLC (Australian Guide to Legal Citation), it clarifies most things. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Considering a [section](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/section) is already a "a distinct part or portion of something written", subsection can seem redundant at first.

But the [definition of subsection](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsection) states:

> a subdivision or a subordinate division of a section

The notion of "placed in or occupying a lower class, rank, or position" is important, and distinct from the definition of "section".
That is why you also find subsection used in sports ("subsection title")

"2.3" is not "a section within "Section 2".
The full meaning of what is in 2.3 is "subordinate" to the general context presented at the beginning in section 2.

Comment: And yet, so many times, I have seen documents which refer to their subsections as sections.

Comment: @Vincent: I agree. I am simply trying to point out a specific difference between the two notions.

Comment: Does that mean the subsection is a section when the section is present but is a subsection in the absence of the section? I.E. if make a citation, I should refer to "subsection 2.3" in order to allude to there being more than just the subordinate section. I ask because the follow up question would be, under what circumstances can I use "section"?

Comment: @mfg: I believe the word "section" is appropriate whenever the global context in which that section is embedded is not necessary to understand the reference you make. But if your reference can be further enriched by the content of the parent section, then "subsection" can be a useful hint to that subordination link.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
4 Section Designations
  a. How to Divide Subsections and Sections
     This is an example. 
     (i) Voila! Have Succeeded in Dividing Them
         This is an example.
```

Section Designations Guidelines:
Refer to the above sections in text:

```
This is an example of a section reference. To see specific example, refer to Section 4 a (i)
```